# A block doesn't want to stand under other blocks

Tags: html, css

I try to make a page and I have a problem with blocks position. I want to place the lower block right under the second one, but it stays at the very top of the page:

[image]
When I add margin to this block, two other blocks move with it.
Here is the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #14000b;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
#top-image {
  background-image: url(../images/top-image.png);
  height: 69px;
  width: 466px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#sub-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #161616;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  visibility: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
#mid-header {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background-color: #161616;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
}
#header-logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 142px;
  background-image: url(../images/header-logo.png);
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #161616;
  height: 60px;
}
.top-menu-list {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
}
.top-menu-list a {
  display: block;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Arial, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.top-menu-list a:hover {
  background-color: #d62952;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
#main-block {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #303030;
  height: 1100px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
#wide-column {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #161616;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 350px;
}
#mid-footer {
  margin: 0 12% 0 12%;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 160px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#sm-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sm-button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.sm-button a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#feedback-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #1a84dd;
}
#feedback-link {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 19px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="top-image">

  </div>

</div>

<div id="sub-header">
  <div id="mid-header">

    <div id="header-buttons">
      <ul id="main-menu">
        <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="index.html" class="top-menu-link">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="#" class="top-menu-link">LIAPEDIA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="#" class="top-menu-link">GUIDES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top-menu-list"><a href="#" class="top-menu-link">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main-block">
  <div id="wide-column">

  </div>

  <div id="small-column">

  </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div id="mid-footer">
    <img src="images/links.png" id="links-label">
    <div id="social-media-buttons">
      <ul id="sm-list">
        <li class="sm-button">
          <a href="http://vk.com/lifeinarena" target="_blank" class="sm-link">
            <img src="images/socvk.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sm-button">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/LifeInArena" target="_blank" class="sm-link">
            <img src="images/soctwitter.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sm-button">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe04DzYZgUIYzwXqZFF1_mA" target="_blank" class="sm-link">
            <img src="images/socyt.png" </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="images/wanttotelussomething.png" id="feedback-label">
    <div id="feedback-button">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" id="feedback-link">Feedback</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you be clearer as to which block belongs where? Perhaps refer to the div elements by the id's that you have given them so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: Remove `float: left;` from `.header` & `#sub-header`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! please try to make your question clearer .. I suggest to remove the work 'block' from your question and replace it with the class name of the div to be more clear

Comment: Thanks, nikhil! The problem was just about floating.